# Ideal correspondence in $R=k[X]/(X^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have a question about the correspondence theorem of ideals in rings:

Let's say we have $R=k[X]/(X^2)$, $k$ being a field. Then all the ideals $I$ in $R$ have a corresponding ideal $J$ in $k[X]$ that contains $(X^2)$. As I see it, there are three possibilities:

1. $J_1=(X^2)$
2. $J_2=(X)$
3. $J_3=k[X]$

To which ideals in $R$ do they correspond to, though? Having a look at the proof I would say

1. $I_1=J_1/(X^2)=(0)$
2. $I_2=J_2/(X^2)=(X)$
3. $I_3=J_3/(X^2)=R$

But this can't be correct, since obviously $(0)$ is an ideal of $k[X]$ which then should also correspond to $(0)$ so the "correspondence" is not 1-1 which it should be. Also the ideal $(0)$ doesn't contain $(X^2)$. Where is my error? Is it simply that the correspondence only works for ideals that contain $(X^2)$? My script is very fishy in this phrasing.

Comment: The theorem is about the correspondence between the ideals of $k[X]/(X^2)$ and the **ideals of $k[X]$ _that contain $(X^2)$._** So in your case, $(0)$ (as an ideal of $k[X]$) doesn't qualify as an ideal that contains $(X^2)$.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Are my $I_{1,2,3}$ correct still?

Comment: They look good, yes!